# Can't figure out why the number won't increment

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code for Javascript, and what I want to do is basically double the number 1, and keep going based on user input. All the code works, except for my for loop. Also, I tried putting spaces for the "steps" but no matter how many spaces I put in the document.write statement, it doesn't reflect in the webpage. Thanks for the help in advance

```
var num=1;
function iterations()
{
    document.write("<b>Sequence of numbers up to iteration number: </b>"+numIterations+"<br>");

    for(var i=1;i<=numIterations;i++)
    {



        var total=num*2;
        if(numIterations<10)
        {
            document.write("<b>STEP "+i+":</b>"+" "+" "+" "+num+"*2="+total+"<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("<b>STEP "+i+":</b>        "+num+"*2="+total+"<br>");
        }
        num*2;


    }



}
var numIterations= prompt("Please enter the upper limit\n\nDo NOT exceed 30");
if(numIterations==null||numIterations>30)
{

    document.write("User enter an invalid (out of range) value");
}
else
{
    iterations();   
}
```

Comment: Remove the var before **total** it is deleting and declaring a new variable called total each time.

Comment: whats value of numIterations? is it a array a number? whats the default value of it?

Comment: How should the sequence look like, if you put in "3" for example?

Comment: numIterations is the value the user inputs based on a prompt alert box

Comment: the sequence should look like this:

STEP 1:      1*2=2
STEP 2:      2*2=4
STEP 3:      4*2=8
...
STEP 10:    512*2=1024

Comment: `num*2;` (below the first `if`-`else` statement) doesn’t do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `*=` your `num` variable so it times it each time, as at the moment you keep replacing it with the same number therefore not working - simple mistake to make so don't worry.

The below works:

```js
var num = 1;
function iterations()
{
    document.write("<b>Sequence of numbers up to iteration number: </b>"+numIterations+"<br>");

    for(var i=1;i<=numIterations;i++)
    {
      
        var total=num*2;
        if(numIterations<10)
        {
            document.write("<b>STEP " + i +":</b>"+" "+" "+" "+num+"*2="+total+"<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("<b>STEP " + i +":</b>"+num+"*2="+total+"<br>");
        }
        num*=2;
    }
}
var numIterations= prompt("Please enter the upper limit\n\nDo NOT exceed 30");
if(numIterations==null||numIterations>30)
{

    document.write("User enter an invalid (out of range) value");
}
else
{
    iterations();   
}
```

Comment: this seemed to work, thank you! now, my other problem is that the spaces that I tried for each "STEP 1:   " doesn't seem to appear that way when I load the webpage. I want the variable num to align with each iteration of num.

Answer (score 1):

you have an error:

the line that says:

```
num*2;
```

replace it with

```
num*=2;
```

use this code, same as above with the above line changed to num*=2;

```
var num=1;
function iterations()
{
    document.write("<b>Sequence of numbers up to iteration number: </b>"+numIterations+"<br>");

    for(var i=1;i<=numIterations;i++)
    {



        var total=num*2;
        if(numIterations<10)
        {
            document.write("<b>STEP "+i+":</b>"+" "+" "+" "+num+"*2="+total+"<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("<b>STEP "+i+":</b>        "+num+"*2="+total+"<br>");
        }
        num*=2;


    }



}
var numIterations= prompt("Please enter the upper limit\n\nDo NOT exceed 30");
if(numIterations==null||numIterations>30)
{

    document.write("User enter an invalid (out of range) value");
}
else
{
    iterations();   
}
```

Comment: The difference is that this is a _semantic_ error, not a syntactic one. With a syntax error a program or script couldn’t even be parsed and executed, with a semantic error however, everything works just fine, _but not as intended_.